# Something like fiddler2 to run in Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, proxy, amazon-ec2, fiddler

I'm running a free instance of Amazon EC2, and I want to make it into a proxy server so that I can inspect traffic from any device which supports setting a proxy. I'm after something like Fiddler2, only linux-based and with a web interface. Does anybody know of any software which does this?

Comment: It would probably be helpful for you to elaborate on why those design requirements exist, and add information about how this relates to programming.

Comment: On a basic level what I want to do is debug HTTP traffic from anywhere. For example, if I wanted to see HTTP requests made by an iPhone application, I'd have to connect it over Wifi and somehow set up fiddler2 on the same network. What I'm thinking is if a similar thing was running in the cloud (only specified EC2 because of low cost) then I could catch traffic from any device simply by setting its proxy server, and easily inspect that traffic from a web interface.

Comment: @mattlyons what did you end up doing?

Comment: Whoa this was so long ago! Honestly probably didn't find anything at the time, but this was the kind of thing I was looking for: https://mitmproxy.org/